# hierarchical mysql query: up and down through parent/children

Tags: mysql, recursion, parent-child, hierarchy, mysql-5.7

I need a query able to retrieve all the parents and all the children (I don't know how many levels there will be) of an entry.
I've used for a while this query but I've now realized that it doesn't work: when I insert a children id it doesn't retrieve the parent.

```
    SELECT id, title, parent FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY id ASC) sorted, 
    (SELECT @pv := ?) initialisation WHERE (FIND_IN_SET(parent, @pv) OR id = @pv) AND length(@pv := CONCAT(@pv, ',', id)) 
    
    UNION 

    SELECT id, title, parent FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY post_id ASC) sorted2, 
    (SELECT @pv2 := @pv) initialisation2 WHERE (FIND_IN_SET(post_id, @pv2) OR parent = @pv2) AND length(@pv2 := CONCAT(@pv2, ',', parent))
```

Example:

```
id   name     parent
4    red      0
20   brown    4
22   blu      20
```

if I set ? = 4 it gets all of them, but if ? is set to 20 it gets only 20 and 22.
Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks

[MySQL v 5.7]

Comment: What is precise MySQL version?

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention the version of MySQL.

MySQL 8.0 implements recursive CTEs that you can use to walk the tree from any node to the leaves.

For example:

```
with recursive
n as (
  select * from table1 where id = 20 -- starting node
 union all
  select t.*
  from n
  join table1 t on t.parent = n.id
)
select * from n;
```

Result:

```
 id  name  parent 
 --- ----- ------ 
 20  red   4      
 22  red   20
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/t11YVNdsF52drvFGYoLnBK/0). In this example you can change the starting node to `4` and get all the rows, or to `22` and only get this last one.

Comment: Yes sorry, it's before MySQL 8.0, so I need to do it manually!

Comment: Also, your solution doesn't work either, because I need to retrieve all three in any case: all the parents (and their own parents) and all the children (and their own children)